# Can not enter into dashboard page using Angular.js UI-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I can not enter the dashboard page after login while using Angular.js. I am providing my code below.

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ng-app="ABSadmin">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>ABSClasses | Admin Panel</title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400italic,600italic,400,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src="js/angularjs.js"></script>
<script src="js/angularuirouter.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/route.js"></script>


  </head>
<body style="background:url(images/533240312.jpg)"  ng-controller="loginController">
<div>
    <div class="logbg">
    <span ng-show="validateMessage" style="color:#C0F">{{message}}</span>
    <h3>Login to Admin Panel</h3>
     <form name="frmlogin" id="frmlogin"  class="login-form">
             <div class="input-box input-left">
                <label for="username">User Name:</label><br>
                <input type="text" id="username" name="username" class="required-entry input-text" ng-model="u_name" ng-keypress="clearField();">
              </div>

            <div class="input-box input-right">
                <label for="login">Password:</label><br>
                <input type="password" id="pwd" name="pwd" class="required-entry input-text" ng-model="u_password" ng-keypress="clearField();">
            </div>
            <input type="button" value="Login" name="login" id="login" class="log" ng-click="adminLogin();" />
    </form>

    </div>
    </div>
<script src="controller/loginController.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The above page is my login page.When user will type `localhost/admin/` this page is coming. the controller file is given below.

```
var login=angular.module('ABSadmin',[]);
login.controller('loginController',function($scope,$http,$location){
    //console.log('hii');
    $scope.adminLogin=function(){
        if($scope.u_name==null || $scope.u_name==''){
            $scope.validateMessage=true;
            $scope.message="Please add user name";
        }else if($scope.u_password==null || $scope.u_password==''){
            $scope.validateMessage=true;
            $scope.message="Please add Password";
        }else{
            $location.path('dashboard');
        }
    }
    $scope.clearField=function(){
        $scope.validateMessage=false;
        $scope.message="";
    }
})
```

After successfully login the user should get into the dashboard page which contains some menu. So here I am using `ui.router` to render the partial view.

route.js:

```
var Dahboard=angular.module('dasboard',['ui.router']);
Dahboard.run(function($rootScope, $state) {
      $rootScope.$state = $state;
 });
Dahboard.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,$locationProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('dashboard');
    $stateProvider
     .state('dashboard', { 
            url: '/dash',
            templateUrl: 'dashboardview/dashboard.html',
            controller: 'dashboardController'
     })
})
```

My dashboard page is given below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ng-app="dasboard">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>ABSClasses | Admin Panel</title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400italic,600italic,400,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="/js/angularjs.js"></script>
<script src="/js/angularuirouter.js"></script>
<script src="/js/route.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="header">
<img src="../images/absclasses-logo-black.png" alt="" /> 
<div style="color:#FFF; font-size:20px; vertical-align:middle; float:left; margin-top:21px;font-weight:bold;  ">Admin Panel</div>
<div class="header-right-pan" >
      <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Logged in as Admin &nbsp;|&nbsp;</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="logout.php"><span class="logout" style="color:#fcce77;text-decoration: underline;" >Log Out</span></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<nav>
    <ul style="width:100%;">
                <li><a href=""></a>
                    <ul>

                                <li>
                                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" style="width:110px;"></a>
                                    <ul class="submenu">
                                        <li><a href="" style="display: block; margin-top: 0px; padding: 4px 15px; width:160px;"> Page</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="" style="display: block; margin-top: 0px; padding: 4px 15px; width:160px;"> Syllabus</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="" style="display: block; margin-top: 0px; padding: 4px 15px; width:160px;">Exam Info</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            <li><a href=""></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>   
    </ul>
</nav>
 <div ui-view>
 <div class="dashbord-body">
    <div>
            <h5>&nbsp;</h5>
    </div>
    <div style="height: 300px; margin: 100px auto; text-align: center;color: #0071b1; font-size: 36px;">Welcome To Admin Panel </div>
</div>
 </div>
<div class="dashbord-body-footer">
  <p class="" style="margin-top: 10px; text-align:center;">
        <img src="images/varien_logo.png" width="19" height="18" alt="" /> 
        Copyright © 2015 OdiTek Solutions. <a target="_blank" href="http://www.oditeksolutions.com" > www.oditeksolutions.com</a>
    </p>
</div>
<script src="js/default.js"></script>
<script src="controller/dashboardController.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here after successfully login the url is coming like this `localhost/admin/#/dashboard` but the dashboard page is not coming still the index page is showing. Here I need after successfull login the dashboard page should come and there I will render partial html file inside `ui-view`.

Answer (score 0):

while you are using angular-ui-router then you have to use

`$state.go('your_state_name');`

instead of `$location.path('dashboard');`

here is your snippet

```
var login=angular.module('ABSadmin',[]);
login.controller('loginController',function($scope,$http,$location, $state){
  $scope.adminLogin=function(){
      if($scope.u_name==null || $scope.u_name==''){
          $scope.validateMessage=true;
          $scope.message="Please add user name";
      }else if($scope.u_password==null || $scope.u_password==''){
          $scope.validateMessage=true;
          $scope.message="Please add Password";
      }else{
          $state.go('dashboard');
      }
  }
  $scope.clearField=function(){
      $scope.validateMessage=false;
      $scope.message="";
  }
})
```

Answer (score -1):

The url for your state in stateProvider is `/dash` not `dashboard`. `dashboard` in this case is your state name. You'll want to tell the `$location` service to take you to

`$location.path('dash')`

You'll also want to change `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise` to point to `/dash` as well since the [urlRouterProvider.otherwise](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#otherwise-for-invalid-routes) method takes a url as a parameter

`$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/dash');`

Comment: While you using Angular-ui-router You have to use $state.go('your_state_name');

Comment: @TheMechanic You don't **have** to use but there's nothing preventing you from doing it. You can use the $location service. I agree, using `$state` is preferable when using ui-router but there's nothing wrong with using $location. Since the user here was using the $location service, I included that in my response.